# Javascript floating menu bar, not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a menu that is positioned on my page, and when the browser window reaches the top of the menu I want it to become fixed to the top of the page and scrolls down with the page like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QqEcC/) however, the code works on that link but will not work when I implement into into my web page. Maybe I am making a simple error, this is how I have implemented the code.

head section:

```
...
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200)
{
    $("#floatbar").css({position:'fixed',left:'0',top:'0'});
}
else
{
    $("#floatbar").css({position:'absolute',left:'0',top:'200px'});
}
});
});
</script>
...
```

body section:

```
...
<div style="height:1000px;width:500px;">

<div id="floatbar" style="background:gray;
                            width:200px;
                            height:40px;
                            position:absolute;
                            left:0;top:200px;">
 <a href="#issue49">Issue 49</a><br />
 <a href="#issue48">Issue 48</a><br />
 <a href="#issue47">Issue 47</a><br />
 <a href="#issue46">Issue 46</a><br />
 </div>
 </div>
 ...
```

Can anyone tell me whats gone wrong, or suggest any idea's as to why this is not working, will not work on dreamweaver live view, safari on mac, firefox on mac or chrome on mac.

Thanks

Jon

Comment: Are you using some other library beside jQuery, e.g. Mootools? Is your code below loading of jQuery library, are you loading jQuery at all?

Comment: I am not loading jQuery at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not loading jQuery at all – Jon
>   Kyte

Well there is your problem. What you have here is jQuery code, it wont work without jQuery.

Paste this somewhere before your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200)
{
    $("#floatbar").css({position:'fixed',left:'0',top:'0'});
}
else
{
    $("#floatbar").css({position:'absolute',left:'0',top:'200px'});
}
});
});
</script>
```

and the magic will happen :)

Comment: So just replace my script type tag with the tag you have used above? will I be able to run this locally or will it have to be run off my server online. I just tried to replace the tag and it still will not work, any ideas?
thanks for the help so far, im new to this!

Comment: Fantastic! I had replaced my script tag, not added it above, thank you so much, you don't realise how much you just saved my ass!

Answer (score 0):

check with this once ..

```
$("#floatbar").css({position:'fixed',left:'0',top:'0',overflow:'hidden'});
```

Comment: Sorry how do you mean check with this? You have added the overflow attribute to the style, this has not seemed to remedy my problem though. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial, it's how I learned:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1810-Creating-A-Sometimes-Fixed-Position-Element-With-jQuery.htm